# Why does the monotone convergence fail here

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, monotone-functions

I am looking at the example $f_{n}(x) = n \chi_{(0, \frac{1}{n}]}$. This converges to $0$ pointwise and graphing it out we can see that its a series of rectangles of area 1 but with growing height.

I can see that the dominated convergence theorem would fail, since I can't find a bound for all $f_{n} as the heights are getting arbitrarily large.

But I cannot see why the Monotone convergence theorem fails. It seems that the sequence is monotone and the value of each individual integral is finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons for which the convergence theorems fail make this example very important.

First, the dominated convergence theorem fails because the function $f\colon x\mapsto \sup_{n\geqslant 1}\left\vert f_n(x)\right\rvert$ is not integrable (it is possible to compute it, if $1/(n_0+1)\lt x\leqslant 1/n_0$, then $f(x)=n_0$. The height of pick does play a role, but we could consider $g_n(x)=\sqrt n\mathbf{1}_{(0,1/n)}$.

For the monotone convergence, we have that for a fixed $x>0$, the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n\geqslant 1}$ increases for values of $n$ smaller than $1/x$ and then is equal to $0$ so $f_n(x)\leqslant f_{n+1}(x)$ holds for $n\geqslant n_0$ but $n_0$ depends on $x$, which spoils the monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Because the sequence you wrote is not monotone. For example, let $x>0.5$ then $f_1(x)=1> f_2(x)=0$.

Comment: Well I feel dumb! Thanks. I shouldn't do math so late!

Comment: @TonyK, It was just an example. You can do a similar thing for any k just by taking $\frac{1}{k}>x>\frac{1}{k+1}$.